# How to add blur effect on top and right side of div?

Tags: css

I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aod4rmx8/

```
.background{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width:50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top:0;
    background-color: #000;
    /*box-shadow: 100px 0 40px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);*/

-webkit-box-shadow: 200px 1px 300px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 200px 1px 300px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 200px 1px 300px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

What i want to achive is to add blur efect on top and right side of black background. This is what i want to achive:

[image]

So that i have a littlebit shadow on image that is on right side, but also to have blur on edge of right and top side of div that have background color. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question, changed my suggestion to this: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/aod4rmx8/2/

Comment: edge of div is still not blur...its rough

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RahulRB1997/aod4rmx8/3/) fiddle almost as per your needs?

Comment: If you could update your sample image with some other colors so we can see how you mean, because now it is very difficult to understand what you mean

Comment: `box-shadow: 200px 1px 300px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;`

Comment: If you combine it with a blur, you get this: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/aod4rmx8/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong, you were asking something like this to add blur effect,

```
.data_protection {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: I can use filer:blur but how can i add shadow on image that is on right side  such as in my fiddle?That is going from left to right...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.data_protection{
 float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
   background-image: url(https://ec.europa.eu/clima/policies/ets/ets-summer-university/sites/clima-ets-summer-university/files/sign%20up%20photo%20-%20typing.JPG);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 400px;

}

.background {
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 40%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -5px, 10px);
    
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding-left: 1200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset -900px 0 0px 10px #000;

}
```

```html
<div class="data_protection">
     <div class="background"></div>
    </div>
```